# Adding addition spacers to bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'd like to add additional spacers to bootstrap 5. I'm including it in sass and overwriting variables.

I want to avoid repeating bootstraps spacer definitions which are :

```
$spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: $spacer * .25,
  2: $spacer * .5,
  3: $spacer,
  4: $spacer * 1.5,
  5: $spacer * 3,
);
```

According to documentation I should be able to add to an existing map without re-declaring existing variables :

[image: adding new map items in bootstrap]

I'd prefer not to re-declare, i'd just like to add an additional item like so :

[image]

Is this possible ?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map-merge` if you first @import the variables.scss which contains the `spacers` declaration..

```
$spacers: map-merge(
    $spacers, (
        6: $spacer * 6,
    )
);
```

https://codeply.com/p/b9jrk23l3m

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but in **v5.3**, this does not work for me.

I had to essentially do it the long way:

```
$custom-spacers: (
  6: $spacer * 4.5
  7: $spacer * 6
);

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities, (
    "padding": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding,
      class: p,
      values: $custom-spacers
    ),
    "padding-top": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding-top,
      class: pt,
      values: $custom-spacers
    ),
    "padding-bottom": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding-bottom,
      class: pb,
      values: $custom-spacers
    ),
    "padding-left": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding-left,
      class: pl,
      values: $custom-spacers
    ),
    "padding-right": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding-right,
      class: pr,
      values: $custom-spacers
    ),
    "padding-x": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding-left padding-right,
      class: px,
      values: $custom-spacers
    ),
    "padding-y": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding-top padding-bottom,
      class: py,
      values: $custom-spacers
    )
  )
);
```