# Adding to a Bootstrap Sass map

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I need more than five options for margin, and I saw the following within Utilities > Spacing for Bootstrap 5.3:

`$spacer: 1rem; $spacers: ( 0: 0, 1: $spacer * .25, 2: $spacer * .5, 3: $spacer, 4: $spacer * 1.5, 5: $spacer * 3, );`

I thought that I may be able to add a sixth option with my own Sass vars file:

`$spacer: 1rem; $spacers: ( 6: $spacer * 4 );`

This didn't do anything at all, so I'm guessing that I need to add it somewhere else instead?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you have to redefine the whole array in a single step - according to the docs it should work to extend the spaces array. Like:
`
$spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: $spacer * 0.25,
  2: $spacer * 0.5,
  3: $spacer,
  4: $spacer * 1.5,
  5: $spacer * 3.125,
  6: $spacer * 4,
);`

Comment: I found a post answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71601997/4584472 - if you want to kind of push a new entry into an existing array you have to use the merge function. Overwriting like I suggested should work as well - merging looks more elegant though :)

Comment: Not sure why this is added as a duplicate for 5.3 since it does not work for my end.

What I had to do was:

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities, (
    "padding": (
      responsive: true,
      property: padding,
      class: p,
      values: $custom-spacers
    ),
);

And do the same for the other padding attributes such as pt, pb, py, px.